# Animations of Sidemenu & Modals faster than own animations

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

The animations of the out and insliding sidemenu or a sliding up modal box from the bottom (Ionic2 Modal) is very fast and smooth.

Now I defined my own animations for floating action buttons. This animation is quite slower than the ionic animations. What is the difference?

Why are my animations a little bit laggy?

```
animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('false', style({
        right: '-500px',
      })),
      state('true',   style({
        right: '0px',
      })),
      transition('false => true', animate('500ms ease-in')),
      transition('true => false', animate('500ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ],
```

Comment: `transition('false'<=>'true',animate('500ms eas-in-out'));`

Comment: I think the easing has nothing to do with the performance and the rendering of the animation..

Comment: Why so? what you exactly want?

Comment: Could you please add more information to the OP? Because it's not clear what you want to accomplish

Comment: I want to make my animations smoother. More performance..

Answer (score 1):

@rakete: I think ionic use the different cubic bezier to control the speed over modal animation. Can you try these below ?

```
transition('false => true', animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.05, 0.36, 1)')
```

And

```
transition('false => true', animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1)')
```

Read more: [Cubic Bezier](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)
Codepen: [cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.66, 0.04, 1)](http://codepen.io/trungk18/pen/dXVmEE)